# Jenkins: Build create react app without Docker

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to build my react application using Jenkins.

I pull the source code from gitlab and trying to execute shell commands:

`npm install && npm run build`

But problem is that `build` executes endlessly and jenkins even crushes!

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "myapplication",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.0.3",
    "react-trumbowyg": "^1.1.0",
    "react-vk": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=80 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

And jenkinks's workspace for this project:

[image]

Logs:

```
Checking out Revision 05de65c3548b48a798ebe2f58f8cf0be59416887 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 05de65c3548b48a798ebe2f58f8cf0be59416887
Commit message: "fix build"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 05de65c3548b48a798ebe2f58f8cf0be59416887 # timeout=10
[static] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins4408353562870979305.sh
+ npm install
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

audited 32091 packages in 43.675s
found 8 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
+ npm run build

> myapplication@0.1.0 build /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/path/to
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Build timed out (after 3 minutes). Marking the build as failed.
Build was aborted
SSH: Current build result is [FAILURE], not going to run.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Most of tutorials I found suggest use docker and CI & DI frameworks.

How to build react application without those?

Comment: Where is it getting stuck? Can you share the console logs?

Comment: @RavindranathBarathy I've added logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npm version was invalid, I've updated it and everything is ok now.

Comment: Needed at least Node v8 something for `{...spread}` used by a dependency

Comment: Do you have details on your build.sh?

Having trouble getting running without docker, which is a constraint in my environment right now.

I can't tell what's being done in your setup that's not being done in mine.

Comment: Can you please share the details regarding how you deployed the build after your build succeeds.

Comment: I am trying to install npm and build it as well, but it is not working.
what did you do? how did you configure it?

Comment: @SukhdeepSinghKalra Sorry, but I do not have the configuration for that project anymore. But most probably you would need ssh access from "build machine" to the place where you want your files, and use a command like `scp`

Comment: @BurreIfort I just followed official instructions from official npm site

Comment: @ChrisGiddings As I remember correctly there were simple commands like `npm install && npm run build`

Comment: I have the same requirement under Jenkins. And I am also doing the same steps that get the source, npm install, npm run build and copy the build using the SCP command to the production server. But my doubt is, for each project, every time is it necessary to install node_modules using npm install as it takes a few minutes to download all and it also insists that Jenkins installed server need the internet access? Is there any way to have node_modules common for all the projects?